# "Enter" key do weird things in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am new to C# and I am trying to make a simple calculator.

if I click a button function `NumClick` will execute. you can see that in my XAML code

```
<Button Name="num1" Content="1" Click="NumClick"/>
```

I found that when I click on any button every thing go ok, but if I then press "Enter" the function `NumClick` (or whatever the last function was called) execute again.

I think What "Enter" do is firing the last event I made.
How to stop that "Enter" Key?

Comment: Have you tried adding `IsDefault="False"` to the button?

Comment: After you clicked on the button, it has the focus so pressing "Enter" reactivates it.
An easy fix would be setting `Focusable` to `False` on the buttons.

Comment: I tried it now, but it didn't fix the problem @greenjaed

Comment: @Ostas 
Now I understand what's happening, I set `Focusable` to `false` in the called functions and that works.
Thanks

Comment: You can set `Focusable` property directly in XAML :)

Comment: Yes, you are right  @MichałTurczyn

Answer (score 0):

use `Keyboard.ClearFocus();`

```
private void NumClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //What needs to be done
   //................
   Keyboard.ClearFocus();
}
```